# Possible Firefox bug that scrolls a background image with background size cover

Tags: css, firefox

I am trying to overlay an image with an animated gradient that has a blend mode set to multiply. The animation is that the gradient moves via background over the image:

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<header></header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(1deg, #db4b23, #f9c914, #36aa50, #f2dc78, #155588, #0096c3),
                url('<?=$post_thumbnail_url?>');
    background-size: 1200% 1200%, cover;

    -webkit-animation: HeaderGradient 240s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation: HeaderGradient 240s ease infinite;
    -o-animation: HeaderGradient 240s ease infinite;
    animation: HeaderGradient 240s ease infinite;

    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
@-webkit-keyframes HeaderGradient {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%, 50% 50%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes HeaderGradient {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%, 50% 50%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%}
}
@-o-keyframes HeaderGradient {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%}
    50%{background-position:50% 100%, 50% 50%}
    100%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%}
}
@keyframes HeaderGradient {
    0%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%; }
    50%{background-position:50% 100%, 50% 50%; }
    100%{background-position:50% 0%, 50% 50%; }
}
```

Here's a working CodePen:

https://codepen.io/AES/pen/Wjpqqz

It works fine in Chrome but when you scroll in Firefox, the background image moves while you scroll. Check out the Pen and scroll the page for a bit. The image will go up as you scroll down.

Any clue what to do?

Comment: Works the same for me in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Currently, the image is a background for the `<header>`, not a fixed background for the whole page. So it's supposed to move up as you scroll down..

Comment: In my Firefox it scrolls up relative to and inside the `<header>`.